# ASP.NET MVC3: Applying a SELECT / WHERE Statement from MVC View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, view

I have list of items contained in viewbag `ViewBag.RoomBookings`

As an example:

I want all the Roombookings with `ViewBag.RoomBookings.RoomNo = 6 AND ViewBag.RoomBookings.Time < DateTime.Now AND ViewBag.RoomBookings.Time < DateTime.Now + 3600`

Looping through is a NO.

And it must be done on the view, as I also need access to all the other roombookings too to populate a timetable.

Alternatively, Im thinking of Hash lists? Where I could list it with RoomNo, and Time and access it that way. But I cant find any good documentation on this if its even possible.

Ive tried a few things (just to test a method that works (these wont follow the same critera as above)):

```
      var RoomBookingsTemp = ViewBag.RoomBookings;

      var newlist = (from RoomOcc in RoomBookingsTemp where RoomOcc.EndDateTime < DateTime.Now select RoomOcc.RoomNo);
      var bookings = RoomBookingsTemp.Where(roombooking => DateCheckStart < roombooking.EndDateTime && DateCheckEnd > roombooking.StartDateTime && roombooking.RoomNo == RoomNo);
      var newlist = RoomBookingsTemp.Select(m => m["RentalNo"]);
```

But none are valid.

Comment: i would think the linq approach you have suggested would do what you are trying to do.  can you state what it is that makes you say it's not valid?

Comment: Works fine in the controller but not the view.

Comment: if linq is the first one, "Query expressions over source type 'dynamic' are not allowed". Other 2 give "Cannot use a lambda expression as an argument to a dynamically dispatched operation without first casting it to a delegate or expression tree type "

Comment: Quoting some worrying phrases from your question: `I have list of items contained in viewbag` and `And it must be done on the view`. Using ViewData/ViewBag, and writing complex code in the view which would otherwise belong to a view model are two very bad practices for me.

Comment: The view is for presentation and shouldn't contain logic. Create the structure you need in the controller and display it in the view

Comment: Whats wrong with having a list in viewbag? I have created the list of room bookings, but need to go through them and put them under the right table headings. (table of rooms against times)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to cast the RoomBookingsTemp variable. When you declare it directly from the ViewBag it's still a dynamic type [[details about viewbag]](http://weblogs.asp.net/hajan/archive/2010/12/11/viewbag-dynamic-in-asp-net-mvc-3-rc-2.aspx) and the error your seeing is that linq can't query/iterate over a dynamic type.

I'm not sure what type you're actually using but try something like this...

```
var RoomBookingsTemp = ViewBag.RoomBookings as List<RoomBooking>;
```

or

```
List<RoomBooking> RoomBookingsTemp = ViewBag.RoomBookings;
```

Comment: *scratches head* I swear I tried this. On second thoughts,maybe I left out the fact its a list of custom objects. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with your second method? You are just missing the select.

```
// Some statements removed from where for clarity
var bookings = RoomBookingsTemp.Where(rb => rb.RoomNo == 6).Select(rb => rb);
```

Comment: "Cannot use a lambda expression as an argument to a dynamically dispatched operation without first casting it to a delegate or expression tree type "

Comment: Can you show the code where you declare RoomBookingsTemp from the ViewBag.

Comment: `var RoomBookingsTemp = ViewBag.RoomBookings`

Comment: It's because ViewBag is dynamic. Either use a statically typed view model (which I highly recommend) or try: List<RoomBookings> RoomBookingsTemp = ViewBag.RoomBookings; // Assuming ViewBag.RoomBookings is a List of RoomBookings